# Replacement for ::SHCreateItemFromParsingName() on Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an app that needs to run on XP, but I want to be able to call ::SHCreateItemFromParsingName() which is only available from Vista onwards.

This:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/04eab1a9-5024-4199-b66c-8d20a83d4af4/shcreateitemfromparsingname-analog-on-xp?forum=vcgeneral

Said:

> I believe you could achieve the same effect as follows: SHParseDisplayName to obtain item PIDL, then SHGetDesktopFolder, and finally IShellFolder::BindToObject

Which I've attempted:

```
IFileDialog *pfd;
....
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
HRESULT hresult = ::SHParseDisplayName(m_path, 0, &pidl, SFGAO_FOLDER, 0);
if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
{
  IShellFolder *psf;
  hresult = ::SHGetDesktopFolder(&psf);

  if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
  {
    IShellItem *child;
    hresult = psf->BindToObject(pidl, 0, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&child);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
    {
      pfd->SetFolder(child);
    }
  }
}
```

I think I'm mainly struggling with the BindToObject (as I'm not a particularly skilled windows programmer!)

Is this even vaguely right?

Comment: The combination of functions to use is `SHParseDisplayName` then `SHCreateShellItem`.

Comment: I'll take a look at that and report back

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat! If you want to put this code in an answer, I'll accept it :)

    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
    HRESULT hresult = ::SHParseDisplayName(m_path, 0, &pidl, SFGAO_FOLDER, 0);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
    {
      IShellItem *psi;
      ::SHCreateShellItem(NULL, NULL, pidl, &psi);
      if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
      {
        pfd->SetFolder(psi);
      }
    }

Comment: Go ahead and write up the answer yourself and accept it, since you are the one who converted my suggestion into a full answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @Raymond Chen comment, this seems to be a working replacement.

```
PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
HRESULT hresult = ::SHParseDisplayName(m_path, 0, &pidl, SFGAO_FOLDER, 0);
if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
{
  IShellItem *psi;
  hresult = ::SHCreateShellItem(NULL, NULL, pidl, &psi);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hresult))
  {
    pfd->SetFolder(psi);
  }
  ILFree(pidl);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the memory for `pidl` after calling `SHCreateShellItem()`. Use `ILFree()` or `CoTaskFreeMem()` for that.